# Allow comment when deleting answer

Tags: feature-request, comments, review, deleted-answers

When reviewing flags (10K tools) it's possible to vote to delete answers. It should be possible to add a comment in that case too, even though the answer has become deleted.

Especially when it's a new user I think it's extremely important to be able to leave a nice comment on why the answer was deleted.

Some options:

1. Allow everyone that can see the deleted answer to comment.
2. Allow those having cast a delete vote to comment.
3. Allow comments from the flag review queue, but not from the post directly.

Comment: Just leave a comment and *then* deletevote.

Comment: Yes, I know that's the obvious order to do it but sometimes I forget and become stuck without being able to explain. Sometimes someone else is fast on the delete button while I'm writing the comment.

Comment: Option 4 - allow commenting within a "grace period" of casting the final delete vote (5 minutes?)... and probably only the person who cast the final delete vote and/or all users who cast a delete vote.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I really like that grace period idea - in general, to have a period of time when things are deleted but you can leave a comment. Often, I comment on an answer saying it's wrong and then the author deletes it while I'm in the middle of typing another comment on how I think they can/should fix it.